# What is the right way to set a dimension parameter?

Tags: programming, dimensions

In the TeXbook Knuth set parameters for dimensions mostly as follows:

```
 \parskip=3pt
```

Other package authors define such parameters without using the equal sign

```
 \parskip30pt
```

Many later authors use the LaTeX `\setlength`

```
 \setlength{\parskip}{30pt}
```

You can even define a `constant` somewhere and write:

```
  \parskip\parsep
```

Even  `\parskip30PT` or even `\parskip10Pt` works!

I favour `\parskip30pt` for macros in a package and `\newlength` for preamble commands in a document. Is there a right way to set a dimension parameter?

Note: here is a short minimal example of all the above commands for anyone wishing to try them out.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \parskip30pt
  \lipsum[1-2]
  \parskip=3pt
  \lipsum[1]
  \setlength{\parskip}{30pt}
  \lipsum[1]
 \parskip\parsep
  \lipsum[1]
 \parskip25Pt
 \lipsum[3]
 \parskip30PT
 \lipsum[4]
\texttt{\meaning\parsep}

\texttt{\the\parsep}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the TeX level there are two register types to worry about, dimensions and skips. The former only take a dimension (not surprisingly), whereas the later also have a rubber component. LaTeX's 'lengths' are TeX skips and so can have a rubber component. This is important when you consider how to terminate the setting instructions. For example:

```
\newskip\myskip
\def\setmyskip#1{\myskip #1} % Bad!
\setmyskip{10 pt} plus some other context
```

Here, TeX will think that 'plus' is part of the skip information and will complain about a missing number. So LaTeX includes a `\relax` in the definition of `\setlength` to avoid this:

```
> \setlength=macro:
#1#2->#1#2\relax .
```

This termination question does not apply in the case where you are setting one length from another:

```
\parskip\parsep plus
```

will not treat the `plus` as part of the setting. Whenever you set one *register* from another TeX 'knows' that there is nothing else to look for. (Note: if you try the same with a constant stored as a macro, you are back needing the `\relax`.)

Now, on the 'right' way to do this I'm not aware of a case where the `=` is vital (contrast the situation with `\let`, where sometimes that optional `=` is significant). So I would not use one.

As LaTeX provides proper termination of the setting, I would prefer it's method over the plain TeX approach if we are talking about a LaTeX document. That said, if I want a fixed length I will tend to prefer a dimension, and use `\newdimen` followed by the plain TeX setting method with `\relax` inserted as appropriate.

Comment: The LaTeX version of `\setlength` of file `latex.ltx` contains the bug [latex/3066](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex%2F3066) that is fixed by package [`fixltx2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e). It inserts a space between `#1` and `#2`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I guess 'bug' here is slightly questionable: `\dimen0` is _not_ LaTeX syntax, so there is no reason (reading _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_) to expect this to work. There was dicussion ages ago within the team about whether `expl3` (`\dim_set:Nn`, _etc._) should support register numbers. We decided it should not, _i.e._ that anything that goes wrong if you do `\dim_set:Nn { \dimen0 } { 10 pt }` is not a bug.

Comment: @JosephWright Please give an example when  `\let` needs an equal sign.

Comment: @marczellm Usual answer is for awkward cases: `\let\foo==` would be a trivial one! (Without the first `=`, you end up with `\foo` equal to whatever the next token is).